# dragging issue in chess table

Tags: c#, drag-and-drop

I have chess table and my elements are now moving according to rules .But when I drag out of rules my button is disappearing...How I can solve it ???
(red buttons are showing where can I go my elements)
for example knight is moving as rules now (if I don't pass over the red buttons there is no problem)but when I pass over the red places and if I drop there the knight disappears and red places turns back to their original color ( no more red places which indicates where my knight can go ). i tried to make debug but since i am new in c# and debugging i haven't solved the problem. i will be happy if u enlighten my way. how can i solve it? thanks

```
        void btn_DragEnter(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
        {
        Button button = (Button)sender;
        e.Effect = DragDropEffects.Move;
        for (int x = 0; x <= 7; x++)
        {
        for (int y = 0; y <= 7; y++)
        {
        btn[x, y].Image = null;
        if ((x + y) % 2 == 0)
        btn[x, y].BackColor = Color.Black;
        else
        btn[x, y].BackColor = Color.White;
        }
        }
        }

        void btn_DragDrop(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
        {
        Button button = (Button)sender;
        button.Image = (Bitmap)e.Data.GetData(DataFormats.Bitmap);

        int[] dizi = (int[])button.Tag;
        int x = dizi[0];
        int y = dizi[1];

        for (int a = 0; a <= 7; a++)
        {
        for (int b = 0; b <= 7; b++)
        {
        btn[a, b].AllowDrop = false;
        }
        }

        if ((x + 1 >= 0 && y + 2 <= 7) && (y + 2 >= 0 && x + 1 <= 7))
        {
        btn[x + 1, y + 2].BackColor = Color.Red;
        btn[x + 1, y + 2].AllowDrop = true;
        }
        if ((x + 1 >= 0 && y - 2 <= 7) && (y - 2 >= 0 && x + 1 <= 7))
        {
        btn[x + 1, y - 2].BackColor = Color.Red;
        btn[x + 1, y - 2].AllowDrop = true;
        }
        if ((x - 1 >= 0 && y + 2 <= 7) && (y + 2 >= 0 && x - 1 <= 7))
        {
        btn[x - 1, y + 2].BackColor = Color.Red;
        btn[x - 1, y + 2].AllowDrop = true;
        }
        if ((x - 1 >= 0 && y - 2 <= 7) && (y - 2 >= 0 && x - 1 <= 7))
        {
        btn[x - 1, y - 2].BackColor = Color.Red;
        btn[x - 1, y - 2].AllowDrop = true;
        }
        if ((x + 2 >= 0 && y + 1 <= 7) && (y + 1 >= 0 && x + 2 <= 7))
        {
        btn[x + 2, y + 1].BackColor = Color.Red;
        btn[x + 2, y + 1].AllowDrop = true;
        }
        if ((x + 2 >= 0 && y - 1 <= 7) && (y - 1 >= 0 && x + 2 <= 7))
        {
        btn[x + 2, y - 1].BackColor = Color.Red;
        btn[x + 2, y - 1].AllowDrop = true;
        }
        if ((x - 2 >= 0 && y + 1 <= 7) && (y + 1 >= 0 && x - 2 <= 7))
        {
        btn[x - 2, y + 1].BackColor = Color.Red;
        btn[x - 2, y + 1].AllowDrop = true;
        }
        if ((x - 2 >= 0 && y - 1 <= 7) && (y - 1 >= 0 && x - 2 <= 7))
        {
        btn[x - 2, y - 1].BackColor = Color.Red;
        btn[x - 2, y - 1].AllowDrop = true;
        }
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

DoDragDrop is called only when actually dropping the piece. Your logic for determining where the piece can be dropped should be run when starting the drag, in MouseDown or MouseMove, before the call to DoDragDrop. It also seems you are clearing the red buttons in the DragEnter function. That also should be done in the MouseDown/MouseMove function, after the call to DoDragDrop.

Comment: ok thanks Alex it helped some. you are right with DragEnter. so i cleared the for loop in DragEnter. and worked fine but this time when i move the knight it moved but the image of the knight stay in the previous position. ( means each time i move the knight previous image of the knight stays.)

Comment: Instead of clearing the for loop in DragEnter, try moving it to the end of DragDrop, or put it after the call to DoDragDrop.

Comment: thanks Alex i appreciated you a lot. it solved the problem. in mousedown event after button.DoDragDrop....statement  i checked if the button backcolar is red then i assigned the button image to null else i assigned the knight image to the button image.